# How to create a pie chart using iOS plot and getting the plot values from textfields

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to creat a pie chart with IOS plot i have downloaded framework but it gets data from plist file whici is static only i want dynamic data for chart whici is calculated by the values entered in textfields.in IOS plot it gets form plist how to sort out this issue and i don't get that how this populating values for section of plot.
this is in separate view i want this in my existing view controller

```
   #import "PieChartViewController.h"
   #import "PCPieChart.h"

   @implementation PieChartViewController

  - (id)init
  {
self = [super init];
if (self)
{
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:1]];
    [self.titleLabel setText:@"Pie Chart"];


    int height = [self.view bounds].size.width/3*2.; // 220;
    int width = [self.view bounds].size.width; //320;
    PCPieChart *pieChart = [[PCPieChart alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(([self.view bounds].size.width-width)/2,([self.view bounds].size.height-height)/2,width,height)];
    [pieChart setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];
    [pieChart setDiameter:width/2];
    [pieChart setSameColorLabel:YES];

    [self.view addSubview:pieChart];
    [pieChart release];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        pieChart.titleFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:30];
        pieChart.percentageFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:50];
    }

//  NSString *sampleFile = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample_piechart_data.plist"];
//  NSDictionary *sampleInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:sampleFile];
    NSMutableArray *components = [NSMutableArray array];


    for (int i=0; i<[[components] count]; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *item = [[sampleInfo objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:i];
        PCPieComponent *component = [PCPieComponent pieComponentWithTitle:[item objectForKey:@"title"] value:[[item objectForKey:@"value"] floatValue]];
        [components addObject:component];

        if (i==0)
        {
            [component setColour:PCColorYellow];
        }
        else if (i==1)
        {
            [component setColour:PCColorGreen];
        }
        else if (i==2)
        {
            [component setColour:PCColorOrange];
        }
        else if (i==3)
        {
            [component setColour:PCColorRed];
        }
        else if (i==4)
        {
            [component setColour:PCColorBlue];
        }
    }
    [pieChart setComponents:components];

    }
    return self;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked with same Framework and faced the same issue , i solved that by using this method , just try that, might work.

```
NSMutableArray *components = [NSMutableArray array];

 NSDictionary *value1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bala", @"title", [NSNumber numberWithInt:13702.79], @"value", nil];
    NSDictionary *value2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Justin", @"title", [NSNumber numberWithInt:130000], @"value", nil];


    NSArray *dictionaryArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:value1, value2,  nil];

    NSDictionary *dataDictonary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:dictionaryArray, @"data", nil];

    NSLog(@"%@", dataDictonary);
    NSMutableArray *components = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i=0; i<[[dataDictonary objectForKey:@"data"] count]; i++)
    {

        NSDictionary *item = [[dataDictonary objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%@ item with inde",item);

        PCPieComponent *component = [PCPieComponent pieComponentWithTitle:[item objectForKey:@"title"] value:[[item objectForKey:@"value"] floatValue]];

        [components addObject:component];

        if (i==0)
        {
            [component setColour:PCColorYellow];
        }
        else if (i==1)
        {
            [component setColour:PCColorGreen];
        }
        else if (i==2)
        {
            [component setColour:PCColorOrange];
        }
        else if (i==3)
        {
            [component setColour:PCColorRed];
        }
        else if (i==4)
        {
            [component setColour:PCColorBlue];
        }
    }
    [pieChart setComponents:components];

}
```

[Here is the Sample Project with your Requirement](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iod5vl0r3ohmjxd/PieChartTuto.zip)